# How to move an array of images randomly in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, uiimageview

How can I move an array of images randomly in iPhone app.

Bellow code is for moving one image. I've to use an array of images.

```
- (void)moveImage:(UIImageView *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
        curve:(int)curve x:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];

    [UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];

    [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];

    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    // The transform matrix
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, y);
    image.transform = transform;

    // Commit the changes
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageToMove =
    [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fish.png"]];

    imageToMove.frame = CGRectMake(70, 120, 100, 100);

    [self.view addSubview:imageToMove];

    [self moveImage:imageToMove duration:1.0
              curve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear x:0.0 y:110.0];

}
```

Comment: You should use CAAnimationGroup for simultaneous animation for multiple objects. check this link for reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAAnimationGroup_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use this it might help you:

```
NSArray *animationArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"],
                                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"img4.png"],
                    nil];
UIImageView *animationView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320, 460)];
    animationView.backgroundColor=[UIColor purpleColor];
    animationView.animationImages=animationArray;
    animationView.animationDuration=1.5;
animationView.animationRepeatCount=0;
    [animationView startAnimating]; 
    [self.view addSubview:animationView];       
    [animationView release];
```

This is just a conceptual code so please make changes according to your need.